# Will I get in trouble if I copy the whole KJV into a book?

Tags: kjv, copyright

The goal is to get my hands on a blank/clean version of the KJV that is in the public domain - One that I could copy freely into a text editor without fear of ever having to deal with copyright issues.

The intent is to copy the entire Bible into my book to add apologetics & commentary to it in the form of foot/side -notes while leaving the text itself entirely unchanged. I'm guessing that this is allowed, but what I mainly need to know is whether there is a specific website from which writers could download the KJV.

[I've found this link](http://ebible.org/kjv/) - perhaps that is what I'm looking for?

I very much thank you for your help.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: I am from Europe, the Netherlands in particular. I actually read the other question that was linked in advance, but I was unsure whether public domain infers that I can freely copy the entire Bible if I wish to do so?

Comment: Yes, that's what public domain means.  The question of whether the KJV is public domain in the Netherlands is a bit more specific, so it may be worth keeping this open for that purpose.

Comment: I did look into it and it seemed like I was good to go as long as I wasn't in the UK. But I agree that it's still worth keeping this open just to make sure. It would be a total waste to spend a few years of my life working on this only to get sued the moment I release it.

Comment: The legal position is that the KJV is out of copyright and therefore "in the public domain". The ethical position is that you must properly attribute material you copy.  Copying an entire book is itself an ethical minefield.

Comment: What do you mean by properly attributing it?